# How can I beat Solo Voyage with Earl?

Tags: hitogata-happa

I easily beat Solo Voyage with all the other dolls. But Earl is driving me crazy. Earl's attack is too weak to beat bosses with it, and her Flow charges too slowly to use bombs.

I'm playing on Eruidice difficulty (easy) to make it easier, but it's not really helping.

I consistently run out of time with Earl against bosses. How can I kill bosses with her? I run out of time on bosses as early as the third boss.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've beaten it as the other dolls, I'm guessing you aren't using much Daath Whisper to help your dodging, since you probably don't really need it. However, your main weapon enjoys a reasonable boost while it's active, so you should make sure to use it.

Still, your bomb charges in about 12 seconds and deals decent damage, so that... isn't terrible. It might be worth saving your mana for making your bombing runs actually successful. If you land a good percentage of your bombs, you'll do fine, and, looking over my completed replay of Solo Voyage Earl on Euridice, this is the strategy I tended toward.

Additionally, much like Rooty, you may find you need to get closer to certain bosses for your beam to not get distracted by other targets.

Comment: Isn't terrible? It's got to be the worst in the game ;P (barring the special dolls). Daath whisper boosts damage slightly, but not enough to matter for bosses. The big problem is living long enough to get off a bomb, and unlike Leaf, DAath Whisper doesn't seem to turbo-boost the Flow gauge.

Comment: Pretty sure Clover is worse at bombing, actually. :) Daath Whisper does indeed not boost the Flow-gauge and living is certainly a problem. I found Earl second hardest, personally, after Peco, so... good luck.

Comment: But Peco was *fun*! Plus she ripped up bosses like no one's business, second only to Sikkim/special dolls. Oh well, I guess I'll just try again

Answer (score 1):

Beating bosses with Earl is all about using bombs at the right time. Try to save your bombs for parts where you know the boss will take a while to die. Also, try not to lose a bomb as it takes a lot to charge.
I'm stuck at the mission 4 boss. Her shot is useless there, she just fires randomly and I always die before I can charge another bomb. It would be great if Joseph could upload his replay for us xD

Comment: As far as I can tell, the file formats Hitogata Happa uses don't actually support just throwing a replay file somewhere for someone to view. I could probably screencapture it sometime if you really want me to, but I'm not sure how valuable an exercise that would really be. I don't think my positioning was that great, and it was Euridice.

Comment: I didn't know replays couldn't be sent like that. Turned out my game was bugged, so I couldn't really finish mission 4 with her. But now I fixed it, and that gives me all the achievements for this game. There's no need for you to record it, but it would still be cool to see how you made it.